# rewrite scala filter in R

Tags: r, scala, databricks

Is there a way to rewrite this code in R?

```
%scala
val source = "/mnt/data.model/tmp"
val target = "/mnt/data.model"
dbutils.fs.mv(dbutils.fs.ls(source).filter(file=>file.name.startsWith("part-00000"))(0).path,target+"/"+"dataset.parquet")
```

Basically, this code is getting from a list of records, only the file that starts with part-00000 then its rename the file when moving to another folder.
There is only one file with part-0000 in the source folder.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. 
It is a good practice to include in the question the codes of what you have already attempted. In your case, as you want to translate a code from one language to another, in the way you are presenting the question, you are really waiting to have someone knowing both languages to make such a favour. Note that the question, as stated, ends up being so broad, and is not much likely to get answered. 
Why you do not translate it to R users to increase the chances? Specifically: (1) translate the scala's code to the objectives/tasks in that code; (2) Include your draft codes you

Answer (score 0):

You can consider something like this :

```
library(stringr)
source <- "/mnt/data.model/tmp"
target <- "/mnt/data.model"
files <- list.files("/mnt/data.model/tmp")
files_To_Move <- files[stringr::str_detect(files, pattern = "part-00000")]
file.copy(from = paste0(source, files_To_Move),
          to = paste0(target, "dataset.parquet/", files_To_Move))
file.remove(paste0(source, files_To_Move))
```